# como realizar una peticion put|patch en laravel?

Tags: ajax, laravel, laravel-5

tengo la siguiente funcion que realiza una llamada ajax para actualizar datos de mi tabla:

```
$("#editar").click(function(){
    if($idfila!=null){
        ruta=url_base+"/patron/"+$idfila;
        var formData = new FormData($("#formulario_datos")[0]);
        formData.append("_token",'{{csrf_token()}}');
        tipo='PATCH';
        myajax(ruta,tipo,formData,function(resp,t){
            if(t=='success'){
                toastr.success(resp.msn);
                limpiar();
                $("#table-contenido").append($html);
                $('.datatables').DataTable();
            }else{
                toastr.error(resp.msn);
                toastr.error(resp.responseJSON.message);
            }
        });
    }else{
        toastr.warning("Seleccione un elemento primero");
    }
    botones(false,true,true,true,true);
});
```

La función `myajax` es la siguiente:

```
function myajax(url,tipo,datos,callback){
    $.ajax({
        url: url,
        type: tipo,
        data: datos,
        contentType:false,
        processData:false,
        success:function(data){
            callback(data,'success');
        },
        error:function(error){
            callback(error,'error');
        }
    });
}
```

y mi formulario es el siguiente:

```
<form method="POST"  id="formulario_datos"  accept-charset="UTF-8">
    {{csrf_field()}}
    <div class="form-group">
        {!!Form::label('nombre','NOMBRE: ', ['class'=>'col-sm-3 col-md-3 col-lg-3 control-label input-sm'])!!} 
        <div class="col-sm-9 col-md-9 col-lg-9">
            {!!Form::text('nombre',null, ['id'=>'nombre', 'class'=>'input-sm', 'required' => 'required','disabled'=>'true'])!!}
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        {!!Form::label('SIMBOLO','SIMBOLO: ', ['class'=>'col-sm-3 col-md-3 col-lg-3 control-label input-sm'])!!} 
        <div class="col-sm-9 col-md-9 col-lg-9">
            {!!Form::text('simbolo',null, ['id'=>'simbolo', 'class'=>'input-sm', 'required' => 'required','disabled'=>'true'])!!}
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        @include("buttons")
    </div>
</form>
```

Cuando intento actulizar los datos, es decir hacer la llamada `ajax` me retorna el siguiente error:

> PATCH http://localhost:8000/patron/EV21A2md 419 (unknown status)

ingresando netamente al error me encontré con:

> exception: "Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Exception\HttpException"
>   file: "C:\xampp\htdocs\VentasAlmacen\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate \Foundation\Exceptions\Handler.php"
>   line: 203
>   message: ""

he leído otros casos en los que dicen que les faltaría el `_token` pero si se fijan en mi `form` la tengo incluida.

Answer (score 0):

La mayoría de navegadores solo aceptan POST o GET, por lo que para que laravel lo interprete usa un helper llamado "method_field" (igual que csrf_token)

```
method="{{ (isset($method)) ? (($method != 'GET')  ? 'POST' : 'GET') : 'GET' }}"
@if($method != 'GET')
    @if($method != 'POST')
       {{ method_field($method) }}
   @endif
@endif
```

Comment: lo incluyo a mi formulario?

Comment: Si, pero deberias comprenderlo mejor que copiar y pegar.